# Functional Test Android Studio

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to understand how functional tests work in android applications. But I have difficulties.
In the case shown below, I check in database if there are any "work" in the database and if this exists, it goes to the WorkActivity activity, otherwise it goes to CalendarActivity.

MainActivity

```
     public void btnNotes(View view) {
        if (userDAO.existWork() == false) {
            Intent intentRegisterWork = new Intent(this, WorkActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentRegisterWork);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalendarActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

MainActivityTest

```
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
    public class MainActivityTest {
        @Rule
        public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivityTestRule =
                new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);
        @Test
        public void testChangeIntent() {
            onView(withId(R.id.btnNotes));
            Intent intent = new Intent (mMainActivityTestRule.getActivity(),WorkActivity.class);
            mMainActivityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

How do I test this?